# slice requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add some values from another list synchronously in the for loop of django ’s template. When I use a given number everything works fine, but when I replace it to `{{forloop.counter}}` it reports an error `slice requires 2 arguments, 1 provided`
I Googled it and the suggestion is that there should be no spaces in the code, but there are no spaces in my code, here the code in question.

```
{% for i in invtypes %}
                    <li>
                        ...
                        <p>{{data|slice:":{{forloop.counter}}"}}</p>
                    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The `{{data}}` is a list of extra data for `invtypes` so they have same length and sort。

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solutions seems to be spaces indeed.

Try:

```
{% for i in invtypes %}
                <li>
                    ...
                    <p>{{ data|slice:":{{ forloop.counter }}" }}</p>
                </li>
{% endfor %}
```

and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I added a colon after **slice** to fix the error.

Before:

```
{{ post.body|slice":200" }}
```

After:

```
{{ post.body|slice:":200" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct solution.

(Wrong) =>

```
{{data|slice: ":{{forloop.counter}}"}}
```

[don't add a space after slice's colon.

(Right) =>

```
{{data|slice:":{{forloop.counter}}"}}
```

If you add a space after slice's colon, it takes only the part which comes before that space and considered it as one argument and second one will be considered as missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the line `{{data|slice:":{{forloop.counter}}"}}` the `":{{forloop.counter}}"` would not work as you expect as if it were performing string interpolation. What can be done to get around this is to use the [`with` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) along with the `add` and `stringformat` template filters to get the required value as a template variable before you try to render that:

```
{% for i in invtypes %}
    <li>
        ...
        {% with str_counter=forloop.counter|stringformat:"i" %}
            {% with slice_var=":"|add:str_counter %}
                <p>{{ data|slice:slice_var }}</p>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endwith %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

One should also note that a need to do this implies that the *view* is not supplying the data to the template in an efficient manner, ideally the template should not be doing all of this manipulation with data. It can be seen that `invtypes` and `data` have some type of relationship but the context given by the view does not convey that at all.